# Get generated HTML after JS manipulates the DOM and pass request headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-parsing, phantomjs

I need to get the generated HTML source of the page after JS DOM manipulation has all been done. I was using Phantomas `https://github.com/macbre/phantomas` for this purpose, but unfortunately it does not provide a way to pass in request headers.

Is there a library out there that will allow to pass request headers and then get the generated HTML source code.

Any pointers would be greatly helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ["PhantomJS WebKit scriptable"](http://phantomjs.org/).

Specify [`customHeaders`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/custom-headers.html) and get the [`page.content`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/content.html):

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.customHeaders = {
  "X-Test": "foo",
  "DNT": "1"
};

page.open('http://phantomjs.org', function (status) {
  var content = page.content;
  console.log('Content: ' + content);
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Save it to `test.js` and run:

```
phantomjs test.js
```

Comment: How can I pass the url through the command line as `phantomjs test.js http://phantomjs.org`

Comment: @user567797 you can read the command-line arguments, [here](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/arguments.js) is an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`casperjs`](http://casperjs.org/).

Pass `headers` in a `settings` object to the [`open()` function](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#open) and use [`getPageContent()`](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#getpagecontent) to get the HTML source of the page:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

var headers = {
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'HEADER-XYZ': 'HEADER-XYZ-DATA'
};

casper.start().then(function () {
    this.open("http://casperjs.org", {
        method: 'get',
        headers: headers
    });
});

casper.then(function() {
    console.log(this.getPageContent());
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.exit();
});
```