# Save entire HTML content with both form data and HTML to server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to save a page that contain a form to a server by sending AJAX with the wanted data. I wish to save the entire webpage *and* the data inserted.

The result should be like when you locally choose  `File -> Save as` in the broswer. Then inserted values are automatically transfered to the value attributes of the form.

Good languages: jQuery, Javascript, HTML5 that is supported in the three last Firefox and Chrome versions.
Not good: Flash, Silverlight, Java etc..

Example:

```
$(document).on('click', '#button_duplicate', function () {
   $.post("save_page", { data: YOUR_ANSWER });
```

Tried, but not working:

- `$(":root").html()`: Gets only the html without inserted values.
- `$(":root").value()` or `$(":root").text()`: No HTML elements.
- Localstorage solutions: I wish to save to server as a file.
- XPCOM and Browser depended solutions such as Firefox `saveDocument()`: I need to support both Firefox and Chrome including not the latest version.

Update: I've found this library that does exactly what I need but saves to local storage, the solution is the same but to be able to save to the server side as a file: http://shaneriley.com/jquery/remember_state/

Comment: just for curiosity... why do you need all the page on server? you generate the html on server side and have the user variable through ajax.. so you can rebuild it, but to what purpose?

Comment: @hjpotter92 `.html()` does not keep values as stated in OP.

Comment: Hi @ElzoValugi, the page dynamic so user can add line or remove line, so the easy way is to save the entire page just as Ctrl-S.
But if you have a solution example I'd be happy to hear

Comment: how about keeping a log of what user added or deleted, like _deleted_lines : 1,2,3; added lines: "abc" in position 2, "bbc" in position 3"_. I would go for the diff approach then to resend the whole page. At some point you may want to see the differences no?

Comment: @ElzoValugi thanks, the purpose is the ease the user using the form so he can save "his own" half edited form, I don't need to extract the data at the end, only to allow the user to save the entire page as a current to state,
If the user added 100 lines the edited 25 and deleted 30 I don't mind. Space and sending pages is also no problem as all is done on one sever with very few users (less then 200).

Comment: check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27596852/get-generated-html-after-js-manipulates-the-dom-and-pass-request-headers

Comment: thanks, but all that is written there is overkill for my purpose,
there must be a nice and easy javascript\ jquery way

Comment: Sounds to me like sending back the whole page is overkill. You say the page is dynamic - is this so they can add fields, for example? Something like having an "add a new record" button that creates a new row of input fields?

Comment: Hi @Eraph, they have a form made of lines, and each line can be duplicated or deleted. I can't understand how to transfer the libary remember state written at the update above to save to file instead to local storage but this will get my purpose.
The reason for the Elzo reefer to is overkill because it is a whole framework, and I just need a small function "save state file" or something of that kind

Comment: The input's that can be added or deleted, are they the same type for the whole form?

Comment: @JonDon what about just saving in the db an array with the data inserted in the form? On page load you can check if the data exist and populate the form with the data. In case they don't exist user will see an empty form. Why do you need to save the html that will be always the same?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do:

- Client side: When save/submit

  - Store whole document/html in a hidden input field before submitting the form
- Server side: (using ASP/PHP or ...)

  - Save the hidden input to a file
  - Loop the form fields and create a data object and save to a file.json
    `data: [{ id: "field1", value: "Arnold" },{...}]`
  - On reopen, pass/inject the data object to a js snippet which loops the items and resets the values

Actually, the original file can have the js snippet already, and when saving the file/file.json, the data object can be injected into the main file prior to save. The file.json can be saved as a "just in case of needing data object only"